# Java: Cannot Iterate Through WebElement List in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, foreach

For some reason this code always prints the title of the first element in list even though I am using an enhanced for loop to iterate through all elements in the list.

```
    List<WebElement> elementList = getAllElements(driver);

    String title = "";
    String[] XPath = {"//*[contains(@id,'itemName')]"};


    for (WebElement singleElement : elementList) {

        try {
            title = singleElement.findElement(By.xpath(XPath[0])).getText();
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

There are 169 elements in the list with different titles but instead of printing 169 different titles, it prints the first title 169 times.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, I found the answer and it has to do with absolute vs. relative XPath search.

To fix this problem all you need to do is change:

```
String[] XPath = {"//*[contains(@id,'itemName')]"};
```

to:

```
String[] XPath = {".//*[contains(@id,'itemName')]"};
```

The extra dot forces it to use relative XPath instead of absolute XPath.

I hope this helps others.